# SUM(a*b) not working

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I have a PHP page running in postgres. I have 3 tables - *workorders*, *wo_parts* and *part2vendor*. I am trying to multiply 2 table column row datas together, ie *wo_parts* has a field called *qty* and *part2vendor* has a field called *cost*. These 2 are joined by *wo_parts.pn* and *part2vendor.pn*. I have created a query like this:

```
$scoreCostQuery = "SELECT SUM(part2vendor.cost*wo_parts.qty) as total_score 
                       FROM part2vendor 
                       INNER JOIN wo_parts 
                         ON (wo_parts.pn=part2vendor.pn)  
                       WHERE workorder=$workorder";
```

But if I add the costs of the parts multiplied by the qauntities supplied, it adds to a different number than what the script is doing. Help....I am new to this but if someone can show me in SQL I can modify it for postgres. Thanks

Comment: Try the query without the SUM and with additional columns `wo_parts.cost, wo_parts.qty` (keep the product of the two). That should show you what data is being summed.

Comment: I updated my answer, but you need to help us in order to help you.  Starting with posting the output to: `DESCRIBE WO_PARTS` and `DESCRIBE PART2VENDOR`

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing example data, there's no way for us to know why you're query totals are coming out differently that when you do the math by hand.  It could be a bad join, so you are getting more/less records than you expected.  It's also possible that your calculations are off.  Pick an example with the smallest number of associated records & compare.

My suggestion is to add a `GROUP BY` to the query:

```
  SELECT SUM(p.cost * wp.qty) as total_score 
    FROM part2vendor p
    JOIN wo_parts wp ON wp.pn = p.pn 
   WHERE workorder = $workorder
GROUP BY workorder
```

FYI: MySQL was [designed to allow flexibility](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) in the `GROUP BY`, while no other db I've used does - it's a source of numerous questions on SO "why does this work in MySQL when it doesn't work on db x...".

### To Check that your Quantities are correct:

```
SELECT wp.qty,
       p.cost
  FROM WO_PARTS wp
  JOIN PART2VENDOR p ON p.pn = wp.pn
 WHERE p.workorder = $workorder
```

Check that the numbers are correct for a given order.

Comment: I have tried this answer and it works. However the totals still don't add up. It works if there is only 1 part. I have the following. 1 x 3.91, 1 x 41.14, 1 x 29.95 and 4 x 19.36. This gives me 152.44. However, when the script uns, the output is 214.85. My code is

Comment: ***$scoreCostQuery = "SELECT SUM(p.cost*wp.qty) as total_score FROM part2vendor p JOIN wo_parts wp ON wp.pn = p.pn WHERE workorder = $workorder
GROUP BY workorder";
$sRow = pg_fetch_array(pg_query($scoreCostQuery));
$cost = $sRow['total_score'];
echo $cost;

Comment: First thing to check is that you are getting accurate counts via SQL query.

Comment: How do I do that. Sorry but I am complete newbie at this whole thing. I have managed to get codes from the net so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a sub-query instead.
*(Note, I don't have a Postgres installation to test this on so consider this more like pseudo code than a working example... It does work in MySQL tho)*

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.`score`) AS 'total_score'
FROM part2vendor AS p2v
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pn, cost * qty AS `score`
    FROM wo_parts
) AS p
    ON p.pn = p2v.pn
WHERE p2n.workorder=$workorder"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you say the `cost` column is in `part2vendor`, but in the query you reference `wo_parts.cost`. If the `wo_parts` table has its own `cost` column, that's the source of the problem.

Comment: I see my error. I have changed this to part2vendor.cost where the cost of the part is. The script runs perfectly but the total it gives is not what I get with a calculator. I have tried this 4 times.

Comment: Did you try my other suggestion about running the query without the sum and two extra columns?